# Why am I unable to initializing a jQuery function within a getScript callback?

Tags: jquery, callback, null, validation, getscript

My specific question/problem has to do with implementing v1.7 of Cedric Dugas' jQuery validation plugin (http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/#comments), BUT I believe the issue can easily be generalized to other situations.

Typically I load the following script like so:

```
<script src="inc/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then to initialize the plugin, I do the following:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#myFormID").validationEngine();
});
</script>
```

I have a form with an id attribute with a value of "myFormID" and the script validates the form fields.  This works.

However, if I include the two bits of code on every page, but the page does not have a form with an ID of myFormID, then I get a null error.  To try to address this problem and make the plugin load only when an appropriate form exists, I tried this:

```
<script>
    if($('#myFormID').length) 
    {
        $.getScript('inc/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js', function() {
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
    };
</script>
```

That works fine too.  However, now I can't figure out how to initialize the validationEngine and bind it to the form.  Why doesn't this work?

```
    $.getScript('inc/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js', function() 
    {
        $("#myFormID").validationEngine();
    });
```

I also tried this:

```
    $.getScript('inc/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js', function() 
    {
        $("#myFormID").load(function()
        {
            $(this).validationEngine();
        });
    });
```

No luck.  I get this error: $("#myFormID") is null.

Ideas?  I'm nearly bald as it is.  This isn't helping!

Comment: Turns out it was a Prototype conflict from a script added by another developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Prototype conflict from a script added by another developer.  There was nothing inherently wrong with

```
<script>
    if($('#myFormID').length) 
    {
        $.getScript('inc/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js', function() {
            $("#myFormID").validationEngine();
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the js in all of your pages, but call validationEngine only when form exists.
Like that:

```
<script src="inc/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
  
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#myFormID').length) 
    {
     $("#myFormID").validationEngine();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but including the js in every page results in an error--that's obviously an issue with the original validation script, but that's out of my control. I just discovered that the reason my code above wasn't working is because of a Prototype conflict from a script added by another developer.  Thanks again, nonetheless.